# Snake game using phaser HTML5 framework

Tags: javascript, beginner, game, snake-game

I am a beginner in JavaScript and Phaser and wrote a Snake game. I think there are lot of things I could have done better. I am looking for some advice on how I can improve the design and refactoring of the code. You can play the game [here](https://boopeshmahendran.github.io/snake-game/).

```
var mainGame = {
    preload: function() {
        game.load.image('snake', 'images/snake.png');
        game.load.image('apple', 'images/apple.png');
    },
    create: function() {
        // data members
        this.snake = [];
        this.initialSnakeLength = 3;
        this.squareSize = 15;
        this.speed = 9;
        this.count = this.speed;
        this.width  = Math.floor(game.world.width / this.squareSize);
        this.height = Math.floor(game.world.height / this.squareSize);
        this.cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        this.direction = "right";
        this.apple = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'apple');
        this.apple.visible = false;
        this.score = 0;
        this.scoreText = game.add.text(10, 10, "", fontStyle);
        this.updateXY = {up: {x: 0, y: -1}, down: {x: 0, y: 1}, left: {x: -1, y: 0}, right: {x: 1, y: 0}};

        this.createSnake();
        this.drawScore();
        this.drawApple();
    },
    update: function() {
        this.updateDirection();
        this.moveSnake();
        this.snakeEatApple();
        this.checkGameOver();
    },
    checkGameOver: function() {
        this.checkOutOfWorld();
        this.checkSnakeCollision();
    },
    checkSnakeCollision: function() {
        var head = this.snake[this.snake.length - 1];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.snake.length - 1; ++i) {
            if (head.x == this.snake[i].x && head.y === this.snake[i].y) {
                this.gameOver();
            }
        }
    },
    checkOutOfWorld: function() {
        var head = this.snake[this.snake.length - 1];
        if (head.x < 0 || head.x > game.world.width || head.y < 0 || head.y > game.world.height) {
            this.gameOver();
        }
    },
    gameOver: function() {
        finalScore = this.score;
        game.state.start('gameOver');
    },
    drawScore: function() {
        this.scoreText.setText("Score: " + this.score);
    },
    createSnake: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.initialSnakeLength; ++i) {
            this.snake.push(this.add.sprite(game.world.centerX + i * this.squareSize, game.world.centerY, 'snake'));
        }
    },
    snakeEatApple: function() {
        var head = this.snake[this.snake.length - 1];
        if (head.x === this.apple.x && head.y === this.apple.y) {
            this.score += 1;
            this.speed = Math.max(4, this.speed - Math.floor((this.score) / 5)); // increment speed
            this.growSnake();
            this.drawScore();
            this.drawApple();
        }
    },
    growSnake: function() {
        var tail = this.snake[0];
        var x = this.snake[this.snake.length - 1].x + this.updateXY[this.direction].x * this.squareSize;
        var y = this.snake[this.snake.length - 1].y + this.updateXY[this.direction].y * this.squareSize;
        this.snake.push(game.add.sprite(x, y, 'snake'));
    },
    moveSnake: function() {
        --this.count;
        if (this.count === 0) {
            this.count = this.speed;
            var tail = this.snake.shift();
            tail.x = this.snake[this.snake.length - 1].x + this.updateXY[this.direction].x * this.squareSize;
            tail.y = this.snake[this.snake.length - 1].y + this.updateXY[this.direction].y * this.squareSize;
            this.snake.push(tail);
        }
    },
    updateDirection: function() {
        if (this.cursors.up.isDown && this.direction != "down") {
            this.direction = "up";
        }
        else if (this.cursors.down.isDown && this.direction != "up") {
            this.direction = "down";
        }
        else if (this.cursors.left.isDown && this.direction != "right") {
            this.direction = "left";
        }
        else if (this.cursors.right.isDown && this.direction != "left") {
            this.direction = "right";
        }
    },
    drawApple: function() {
        var posX = game.rnd.integerInRange(0, this.width - 1);
        var posY = game.rnd.integerInRange(0, this.height - 1);
        var collidingWithSnake = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.snake.length; ++i) {
            if (posX === this.snake[i].x && posY === this.snake[i].y) {
                collidingWithSnake = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!collidingWithSnake) this.apple.reset(posX * this.squareSize, posY * this.squareSize);
        else this.drawApple();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really excellent code for a beginner.  The high-level structure is clear, and that's one of the most important and difficult things to get right.

This isn't a full critique, but I did notice one function where you can remove a lot of repitition.  You can rewrite:

```
updateDirection: function() {
    if (this.cursors.up.isDown && this.direction != "down") {
        this.direction = "up";
    }
    else if (this.cursors.down.isDown && this.direction != "up") {
        this.direction = "down";
    }
    else if (this.cursors.left.isDown && this.direction != "right") {
        this.direction = "left";
    }
    else if (this.cursors.right.isDown && this.direction != "left") {
        this.direction = "right";
    }
},
```

as:

```
updateDirection: function() {
  const opposites  = {down: 'up', up: 'down', left: 'right', right: 'left' };
  const directions = Object.keys(opposites);
  const isPressed  = d => this.cursors[d].isDown;
  const isLegal    = d => this[d] != opposites[d];
  const newDir     = directions.find(d => isPressed(d) && isLegal(d));
  if (newDir) this.direction = newDir;
},
```

Note: the above is untested, but hopefully helpful.  Also note, if needed for performance, you can pull the constants `opposites` and `directions` and `isPressed` and `isLegal` out of the function, so they won't be recreated each time it's called.  The "work" of the function is all accomplished in the final two lines.